# How to make page columns in RDLC Report?

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have a Bulk Data with ID and Name Columns. Now I want to have the report in below format:

ID Name  ID Name  ID Name ID Name
1  x     6  y     11  z   16 f
.
.
.
.
5 f      10 l     15  n   20 a
I want to populate the table in left to right direction if Page1 filled thus then I want to go to Page2 and follow the same steps.

How can i design this report?

It would be great if you people help me to do the same.

#TIA